# Yii Gridview show image from related data

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i have table feedback and user, i am trying to show user's image on feedback page.
i am using grid view, this is my gridview.

```
        [   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '20px'],
            'format' => 'image',
            'value'=>  function($data) { return $data->imageurl; },
        ],
```

and the model

```
public function getImageurl()
{
    return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/../../'.$this->hasOne(User::className(), ['photo' => 'photo']);

}
```

i get right url but the photoname is wrong the result is "photo", i want getting the data form entity photo?

Comment: It would help to know your models and how they are related, because from what i can see 'photo' should be the foreign key that relates both models but i don't think it is. Also, from that statement yo are concatenating the base url with the active record object, not the actual photo field.

Comment: Also it would help to know how you are storing the photos, because you could be using aliases instead of BaseUrl to create the image url.

Comment: @marche i am not sure about the model feedback were created. becouse, i am just add the Photo entity in table user. and user has many feedback, feedback has one user.

Comment: So let me confirm this: User has a field called 'photo', feedback has one User and you are trying to get the photo of the User from the current feedback?

Comment: oh ya thats right, i am sorry for the confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your model you should have a way to get the User related to your feedback like this:

```
public function getUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

Then your getImageurl method should look something like this:

```
public function getImageurl()
{
    return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/../../'.$this->user->photo;
}
```

I would recommend checking out [Aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html), you can use them instead of `\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl`. For example, this is the implementation i use to get a file url to show to the user:

```
public function getFileUrl() {
    return Yii::getAlias('@web/uploads/'.$this->fileName);
}
```